# How to remove the "is" from JAXB generated boolean getters

Tags: java, jaxb

JAXB is generating methods such as:
`isIsBuyNow()` and `isHasBuyNow()` when I want `isBuyNow()` or `hasBuyNow()`.

There are many many class methods being generated, so individually customizing the generated method names is not feasible.

Some sort of regex rule to customise the JAXB is the first thing that came to mind, but I can't find any such general way to change method names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it you only need to change method names, not class names.  You may be able to either:

1. find an XJC plugin that allows this, or
2. write an XJC plugin that does this

I doubt the first option exists (though you might get lucky), but the second option seems pretty straightforward.  See [this page](http://jaxb.java.net/plugin.html) for some posts on how to write your own.

Comment: You can customize the property name using a standard (JSR-222) external binding file, and don't require an external plug-in:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9127208/383861

Comment: Please look at detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606248/jaxb-convert-non-ascii-characters-to-ascii-characters/21780020#21780020 how to write similar Naming plugin

Answer (score 5):

You can use an external bindings file to customize your property name.  In order for JAXB to recognize the method as a property it must follow the convention of starting with `get` or `is` for boolean types.

**schema.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:complexType name="root">
      <xs:attribute name="is-buy-now" type="xs:boolean"/>
   </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**bindings.xml**

In the bindings file below we have specified a property name for the XML attribute called `is-buy-now`:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="is.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='root']/xs:attribute[@name='is-buy-now']">
        <jxb:property name="buyNow"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The `-b` option is used to specify a bindings file:

```
xjc -d out -b bindings.xml schema.xsd
```

**Root**

As a result the following class will be generated with: `isBuyNow` and `setBuyNow` methods:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.02.03 at 05:18:59 AM EST 
//


package generated;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for root complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="root">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;attribute name="is-buy-now" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "is-buy-now")
    protected Boolean buyNow;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the buyNow property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isBuyNow() {
        return buyNow;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the buyNow property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setBuyNow(Boolean value) {
        this.buyNow = value;
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you start from Java classes you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to map to fields and name your methods as you choose:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute(name="has-buy-now")
    private boolean buyNow;

    public boolean hasBuyNow() {
        return buyNow;
    }

}
```

Comment: If there are say, 100 methods, is-buy-now, is-expired, is-reserve-met etc, it seems this solution would have me writing hundreds of lines in the bindings.xml file Is this the case, or have I missunderstood?

Comment: With this approach you are correct.  If you have many of these properties you could take advantage of the approach given by @KalebBrasee:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9123497/383861

Answer (score 2):

Before marching the plugin route. I would emphasize corercting your variables name. It should be as per Java Bean conventions. And JAXB should be  working as per that only.

so if the variable is boolean, ist should idealy be buyNow. Respective getter method will become isBuyNow() only which you want. It would be matter of regenerating the mappings again. No regeex no custom find/replace as you (rightly) want :)

Comment: The schema I am using is 3rd party and I don't have the option of changing it, unfortunately.

Comment: Ohh I should have guessed that :(

Comment: You might be able to give a different propertyName as mentioned in  customizingg property binbdings in tyhe liunk here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148590

Comment: +1 for Java Bean conventions and your link.  I have an answer with a complete example if you are interested:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9127208/383861